# How to configure the end of user space address on 32 bit Linux

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel

I want to reserve some space, e.g. 32MB of memory, between TASK_SIZE(0xC0000000 in 32 bit Linux) and the stack. So I'm wondering is there any way to re-configure the end of the user space address? Like configure the kernel (.config) or some other ways?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you'll have to change TASK_SIZE *in* the kernel source tree, rebuild and boot from the modified kernel.

Useful documentation concerning kernel VM layout:
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt : however this doc covers the x86_64 kernel VM layout, not the i386 (that's simpler though)
- https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/arm/memory.txt : wrt ARM-32

Comment: Oh, I think I have to make it clear.   I want to make TASK_SIZE unchanged, and reserve 32 MB below address 0xC0000000. So the kernel will not use the memory between [3G-32MB, 3G]. The stack, and all the other data are all located below 3G-32MB. I hope to make it by re-configuring the kernel configuration or slightly modifying the kernel code.

Comment: Is your target x86 or ARM-32? I ask as ARM-32 already does this: it keeps 16 MB below TASK_SIZE for kernel module vaddr space. You can see this in the ARM-32 doc I referred to above:
"MODULES_VADDR MODULES_END-1 Kernel module space
    Kernel modules inserted via insmod are
    placed here using dynamic mappings.
"

Comment: Oh, sorry. My target is 32-bit x86 platform.